# How to fill a review form

Tags: peer-review, review-articles

I am preparing to send a review report for the International Journal of Adaptive Control and Signal Processing, I wrote all the comments about the paper in Word Document when I log in to my account to attach the file, In the review form there is a called **comments to the author**, should I rewrite the comments located in the Word Document or what?

is the file attached will be visible to the authors?

Comment: The straight forward answer is YES. Make sure you have not been offensive in your comments. Based on these comments, the authors would prepare their improved manuscript (if any).

Answer (score 2):

The review submission page is more or less similar for many different platforms such as EditorialManager, EES (EVISE), ManuscriptCentral etc.

You would find at least the following three sections after you log into the page:

1. Rating of the manuscript
2. Comments to the authors
3. Comments to the editor

**1. Rating of the manuscript**

In this section, you will find pointwise portions of the assessment of the manuscript in terms of novelty, originality, writing style etc. which are related to the research work. You may probably asked to enter the rating on a scale of 1-5 or 1-10 (based on how the interface has been designed)

**2. Comments to the authors**

This is the comment section where you are either allowed to attach a file or enter your comments in the text area provided there. You must not be offensive in your comments. It is better to be slightly descriptive and positive in review comments which would help the authors to improve their research or the manuscript.

**3. Comments to the editor**

This section is **confidential** (mostly). Here, if you want to share something privately with the editor **only**, then you can. For example, if you think that the research is plagiarized or something like that. Or, sometimes, you can also praise a paper, if it worth it. This section would make the editor's task easy at least to some extent.